# Complex MySQL Select Left Join Optimization Indexing

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a very complex query that is running and finding locations of members joining the subscription details and sorting by distance.

Can someone provide instruction on the correct indexes and cardinality I should add to make this load faster.

Right now on 1 million records it takes 75 seconds and I know it can be improved.

Thank you.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS (((acos(sin((33.987541*pi()/180)) * sin((users_data.lat*pi()/180))+cos((33.987541*pi()/180)) * cos((users_data.lat*pi()/180)) * cos(((-118.472153- users_data.lon)* pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) as distance,subscription_types.location_limit as location_limit,users_data.user_id,users_data.last_name,users_data.filename,users_data.user_id,users_data.phone_number,users_data.city,users_data.state_code,users_data.zip_code,users_data.country_code,users_data.quote,users_data.subscription_id,users_data.company,users_data.position,users_data.profession_id,users_data.experience,users_data.account_type,users_data.verified,users_data.nationwide,IF(listing_type = 'Company', company, last_name) as name
FROM `users_data`
LEFT JOIN `users_reviews` ON users_data.user_id=users_reviews.user_id AND users_reviews.review_status='2'
LEFT JOIN users_locations ON users_locations.user_id=users_data.user_id
LEFT JOIN subscription_types ON  users_data.subscription_id=subscription_types.subscription_id
WHERE users_data.active='2'
AND subscription_types.searchable='1'
AND users_data.state_code='CA'
AND users_data.country_code='US'
GROUP BY users_data.user_id
HAVING distance <= '50'
OR location_limit='all'
OR users_data.nationwide='1'
ORDER BY subscription_types.search_priority ASC, distance ASC
LIMIT 0,10
```

EXPLAIN

> id    select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
>   1     SIMPLE  users_reviews   system  user_id,review_status   NULL    NULL    NULL    0   const row not found
>   1     SIMPLE  users_locations     system  user_id     NULL    NULL    NULL    0   const row not found
>   1     SIMPLE  users_data  ref     subscription_id,active,state_code,country_code  state_code  47  const   88241   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
>   1     SIMPLE  subscription_types  ALL     PRIMARY,searchable  NULL    NULL    NULL    4   Using where; Using join buffer

Comment: if it doesn't change often you could cache the results and as soon as someone updates something run the query and cache the new out come.

Comment: Why are you forcing index to `(users_data.lat,users_data.lon)`? Those columns aren't used in the JOIN or WHERE.

Comment: Try using an INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN. It doesn't look like you want non-matching rows, because you specify `subscription_types.searchable` in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is not always faster. Often times it is considerably slower. Post explain.

Comment: @Barmar usually left join+where is faster, but not always and not significantly so

Comment: I added the explain above.

Comment: Hi @AdrianBR you are right. I found that using SELECT COUNT(*) with a second query reduces query time by 10x. Also first selecting your database with the least rows first dramatically increases query time. so in my case SELECT.... FROM `subscription_types` JOIN `users_data` also helped. I posted the new query here that I need some help on to get under 1 second . Any help is appreciated! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393104/mysql-spatial-indexing-with-multiple-left-join-on-large-database

Answer (score 2):

You query is not that complex. You have only one join, on a table `subscription_types` which is certainly a little table with no more than a few hundred rows.

- Where are your indexes ? The best way to improve your query is to create indexes on the field you are filtering, like `active`, `country_code`, `state_code` and `searchable`
- Have you create the foreign key on `users_data.subscription_id` ? You need an index on that too.
- `ForceIndex` is useless, let the RDBMS determine the best indexes to chose.
- Left Join is useless too, because the line `subscription_types.searchable='1'` will remove the unmatch correspondance
- The order on `search_priority` implies that you need indexes on this columns too
- The filtering in the `HAVING` can make the indexes not used. You don't need to put these filters in the `HAVING`. If I understand your table schema, this is not really the aggregate that is filtered.

Your table contains 1 million rows, but how much rows are returned, without the limit? With the right indexes, the query should execute under a second.

```
SELECT ...
FROM `users_data`
    INNER JOIN subscription_types 
        ON users_data.subscription_id = subscription_types.subscription_id 
WHERE users_data.active='2' 
  AND users_data.country_code='US' 
  AND users_data.state_code='NY'
  AND subscription_types.searchable='1'
  AND (distance <= '50' OR location_limit='all' OR users_data.nationwide='1')
GROUP BY users_data.user_id 
ORDER BY subscription_types.search_priority ASC, distance ASC 
LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: +1 but i have to disagree with you about "ForceIndex is useless" ... it is very useful in case you index cardinality is not up to date and the RDMS chooses a weaker index or even chooses not to use a index at all

Comment: I think that 99.9% of the queries doesn't need you to specify how to use indexes. It can happens, but prove me that with the execution plan first!

Comment: i agree in order to take a decision like that you need to see first the `EXPLAIN` output

Comment: Hi Guys, I have posted an updated query here that includes the geolocation aspect. I also found that by first selecting your database with the least number of rows first it will dramatically increase your load time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20393104/mysql-spatial-indexing-with-multiple-left-join-on-large-database